# Can preloaded text for edit pages use templates that change depending on page creator's wishes?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm making a collaborative fiction writing site with MediaWiki that will host stories by different authors. Some stories will allow any kind of editing, others just minor changes, others just typo fixes, others no changes at all except after discussion, etc.

I found the way to change MediaWiki:copyrightwarning2, and put I generalized message there, but I'd really like a way for authors to customize a page that gets pulled in, perhaps by a template, into preload text that appears at the top of the edit page.

If it's just for all pages they've authored, that would be fine, but ideally it could be on a per-story basis.

Is there a way to implement such a thing?

Comment: See [Wikipedia:Editnotice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Editnotice).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to define a [page form](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms) and make it a [default form](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/The_%22edit_with_form%22_tab).